# React router displaying Multiple components at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to have multiple routes, so I can redirect from one to another, but every time I add another route, the main app renders the styles and the components at the same time, I've tried lazyLoad, Switch and to add the "exact" in the Route path

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import HomePage from './components/homePage/homePage';
 import SignInForm from './components/signInForm/signInForm';


function App() {
  return (
 <div>
  <Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route exact path="/Sign-In" component={SignInForm} />
  </Switch>
   </Router>
 </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that. https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-smoke-zx8qi?file=/src/App.js. What do you mean by *the main app renders the styles and the components at the same time*?

Comment: I want that it loads only one page, and that is the home page, but it loads the sign in form as well and its styles too

Comment: You mean it should only fetch the code for the component of the current route?

Comment: Yeah, but when I add it loads both of them at the same time, I want them separated, when I click for instance a button for Sign in, I want that it redirects me to sign in

Comment: If you want your components to be bundled and loaded independently you need to prepare them for code splitting. See https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html for details.

Comment: But you should also write your styles so that they do not interfere with each other anyways. So loading your "sign-in" styles should not break your "homepage" styles. If they do you didn't scope them properly.

Comment: Yeah the problem was with Classes, fixed it, thanks to everyone who helped out :) means a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your case i thin you should use another order of your components:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/Sign-In" component={SignInForm} />
    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

`Switch` checks the routes from up and goes down, in your case both are "exact", so it displays both.

You don't even need exact, if you keep the correct order of paths.

Comment: The two routes can't both be `exact` matches at the same time.

Comment: @trixn I supouse you're right, but i've seen this behavior in the ```Switch``` that takes more than one component and it threats them like ```exact```, my solution was always to keep the ```/``` path always last. That's why I wrote "exact" not ```exact```

Comment: switched the order, removed the exact, but it still doesn't work, it still changes the styling of the homepage when I add the Sign In route

Comment: @StrahinjaBabic the styles are a different thing, the important thing is not make them load one above the other.

Comment: I think what OP whats is code splitting and lazy loading but i'm not sure about that ^^

Comment: @StrahinjaBabic I think you have a misunderstanding about how your code is bundled and served to the client. Imports happen at compile time. As soon as you import any file it will be bundled into your `js` and `css`. React-Router doesn't split your code into chunks, it only renders it conditionally at run-time.